# Extend assertRaises

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am writing unit tests that have repetitive code, which I'd like to simplify. My test case runs several scenarios where an HTTP call is expected to fail with a specified status code and an error message. I'm using [`unittest.assertRaises()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises), like so:

```
with self.assertRaises(MyHTTPClientError) as er:
    await my_http_request()
self.assertEqual(er.exception.code, 404, er.exception)
error_msg = json.loads(er.exception.response.body)["error_description"]
self.assertEqual(error_msg, "Not found")
```

To make the code more DRY and easier to read, I'd like to write a custom method `assertRaisesHTTPError()` inside my test case class so that the above snippet is simplified to:

```
with self.assertRaisesHTTPError(404, "Not found") as er:
    await my_http_request()
```

I am stuck at writing the code. So far I got this, but I don't know how to invoke the "body" of the with-statement.

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def assertRaisesHTTPError(self, code: int, error_message: str, *args: Any,
                              **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        with self.assertRaises(MyHTTPClientError) as er:
            ### What goes here ? ###

        self.assertEqual(er.exception.code, code)
        actual_error_message = json.loads(
            er.exception.response.body)["error_description"]
        self.assertEqual(actual_error_message, error_message)
        return er
```

Comment: It would be the same as the body outside the method (ie `await my_http_request()`) is there a reason you can simply call that?

Comment: `my_http_request()` is just a place_holder. It usually takes arguments which vary between scenarios.

Comment: can you just pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to the method? something like `await my_http_request(*args, **kwargs)`? If not you can just add two more arguments to `assertRaisesHTTPError` to take the method's arguments for you and pass them in the same way

Comment: Sometimes there are further method calls necessary. So ideally I'd like to invoke the whole body of the with-statement without making any assumptions of its content.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to be able to handle multiple different bodies your best best it probably to take a function reference as an argument to your custom assert. For example:

```py
from typing import Callable

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertRaisesCustom(self, func: Callable[[], None]) -> Any:
        with self.assertRaises(MyHTTPClientError) as er:
            func()

    def test_something(self):
        def do_something(n: int):
            raise ValueError("something bad happened")
        self.assertRaisesCustom(lambda: do_something(n))
```